# Tag-page doesn't display the date (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display the date of a page within my tags-overview-page on wordpress but it only gets displayed for the first page preview not for the other ones. The other content though (header and excerpt) get echoed correctly so I guess there is no issue with the loop.

That's my markup:

```
    <?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="col col-4 kategorie_block">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <h6>&rarrlp;
                    <?php the_date(); ?>
                </h6>
<!-- ......... Other elements with simple things like <h1> <?php the_title(); ?> on the same hierarchy  ... -->
}
}
```

And what happens, is that all preview blocks do have all necessary content. Just the date is only displayed for the first preview and for all other preview boxes just ↬ gets echoed.

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for duplicate content. the answer is already here:
[Display wordpress posts using get_posts - first post shows no date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416214/display-wordpress-posts-using-get-posts-first-post-shows-no-date?rq=1)

And basically you have to switch to `echo get_the_date();` to display the date for all looped blocks.

Comment: This is correct. `the_date()` will display the same date for each post returned in the loop. You should use `get_the_date()` -- and to be extra safe, I like to pass the ID via `get_the_date()` as well.